# Upload extension in to app store with .crx and some addition files

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've developed extension for Chrome and I want to upload it in to Crome app store, but the issue is in that I have not only .crx file, which is needed but also some other files and dlls which should be installed in to "program files" folder.
So how can I upload my extension in to app store with .crx and some addition files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I can't think of any reason why a Chrome Extension would need to install any DLLs, it is possible according to the [Chrome Extension Developer FAQ](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq.html#faq-dev-06). You'll end up using the [NPAPI Plugin](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) to access your DLLs, though you will need to go through an additional security review before your application gets published.